# Alter Django Admin TabularInline Width

Tags: django, django-admin

In the admin the TabularInline is great. My issue is that I have an inline with a lot of fields and ideally would want the fields that dont fit to move onto a new line. Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could probably hack the template, but perhaps in this instance a StackedInline would be better?